# jQuery-ui autocomplete: value not replacing one input field and handling multiple rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've recently had to upgrade my jQuery (because of a later version of markItUp)) and I'm trying to convert a script/form from the old Autocomplete-jQuery plugin (1.1pre circa 2007) to the newer jQuery-ui method. I've been reading far too many tutorials so my head's getting fuzzy and though I have the basics working there are some issues.

First the basic form and script:

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/auto/main.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/forms/action.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
Reporter (Last, First Middle):<br />
<input type="text" id="last_1" name="lastreporters[]" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" />, 
<input type="text" id="first_1" name="firstreporters[]" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" />
<input type="text" id="middle_1" name="middlereporters[]" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" /><br />
<input type="text" id="last_2" name="lastreporters[]" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" />, 
<input type="text" id="first_2" name="firstreporters[]" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" />
<input type="text" id="middle_2" name="middlereporters[]" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" /><br />
<input type="text" id="last_3" name="lastreporters[]" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" />, 
<input type="text" id="first_3" name="firstreporters[]" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" />
<input type="text" id="middle_3" name="middlereporters[]" size="15" maxlength="30" value="" /><br />
<input type="SUBMIT" value="Insert Data" /><input type="RESET" value="Reset" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[id^='last_']").autocomplete({
source:'/include/reporters.php',
minLength:2,
select: function(event, ui){ 
$("#first_1").val(ui.item.first); 
$("#middle_1").val(ui.item.middle); 
$("#last_1").val(ui.item.last);
}
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've got this part working: If I type in the first two letters of my last name into the last_1 input, the following JSON is sent from my php script:

```
[{"id":"Evans","value":"Ian Evans","label":"Ian Evans","first":"Ian","middle":"","last":"Evans"}]
```

If I select *Ian Evans*, #middle_1 and #first_1 are replaced with their values. However, #last_1 is filled with *Ian Evans*. If I have `$("#last_1").val(ui.item.last);` in my script, why is the full name value going in there instead of the value of last, which is *Evans*?

Secondly, my old script (which was written for me) was able to handle the multiple name lines (last_1,last_2,last_3, etc) placing the first_*X*, middle_*x* data in the right fields. For my working example, I've hardcoded the `$("#first_1").val(ui.item.first);` etc just to get my example working. How would I change the script so that it would place the data in the corresponding _*X* line no matter how many there are?

The previous author had a part of the script that somehow counted the _*X*s but I can't see how that would be used/triggered in the newer jQuery-ui syntax. This is what he had:

```
$("input[id^='last_']").result(function(event, data, formatted){

    var ids=this.id.split('_')
    var id=ids[1]; // from last_xx got xxx

    var s=data[0].split(",");

    $(this).next().focus();
    $(this).next().select();

    //have only last value -- TAB pressed
    if(s.length==1)return;

    $('#first_'+id).val(s[0]);
    $('#middle_'+id).val(s[1]);
    $('#last_'+id).val(s[2]);
});
```

I'm really trying to begin understanding jQuery, but as I try to update this script, these last two items are befuddling me.

Thanks. Here's an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalhit/wczrv9by/

UPDATE #1: Added `return false;` to the select function. That solved the first stumbling block of the drop down value going into the input instead of `ui.item.last`. One last stumbling block: How do I make the select dynamic so that if the dropdown is in last_1 it updates Last_1, first_1, and middle_1 and if it's in last_3 it updates Last_3, first_3, and middle_3?

Comment: hmm interesting, could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net and replicate the same

Comment: @dreamweiver I've never used jsfiddle before. If I don't want an external site making ajax calls to my db, how do I do sample names data for the autocomplete? Thanks.

Comment: @dreamweiver here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalhit/wczrv9by/

Comment: May have solved my second problem by adding `var ids=this.id.split('_');var id=ids[1];$('#first_'+id).val(ui.item.first);` etc, Have updated jsfiddle. Will test it further and if it works, answer my question.